# iptables rule not working on docker

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, docker

I have some containers running on different ports such as 80, 9010 and so on. For example:

```
docker run -d [some other configs] --restart=always -p 9010:443 -p 9010:443/udp xxx/myImage 
#myImage is FROM python:3.6-alpine
```

I want to prevent all connections from outside of host to 9010.
I use many command to restrict it even I write this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT # Allow SSH
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP # Drop eveything else
```

But it just close ports by native services not services runs by docker.
Furthermore, I write some rules for DOCKER-USER chain:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ext_if ! -s 192.168.1.1 -j DROP
```

It also not affected and every time I can telnet to 9010 successfully.

For last try, I disable docker-proxy and enable iptables in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    "userland-proxy": false,
    "iptables": true,
    "ipv6": false
}
```

But not work. I checked many answers but no one works for me; for example this answer.
[Docker meet firewall - finally an answer](https://unrouted.io/2017/08/15/docker-firewall/)

Comment: `and enable iptables` were they disabled before? In any case, if you have iptables enabled and list all the rules you should be able to trace how the packet is processed to a point where you new rule is. Should it reach the rule? Does it get caught by another rule that ACCEPTs the packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my iptables

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           udp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           udp dpt:443
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           udp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.5           tcp dpt:1443
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.5           udp dpt:1443

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

For limit incoming packets when using docker we must limit **DOCKER** chain for example:

```
iptables -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 172.17.0.3 -j DROP
```

For limit outgoing packets when using docker we can limit by **FORWARD** chain like this:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  172.17.0.3           anywhere             quota: 50000000000 bytes
DROP       all  --  172.17.0.3           anywhere
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

You not need iptables to prevent external connections. If you look at the [examples](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose:%7E:text=data%20busybox%20sh-,Publish%20or%20expose%20port,-(%2Dp%2C%20%2D%2Dexpose)) for how to expose ports (`-p` option), we can specify which IP is used to listen for incoming connections. The default is to listen on `0.0.0.0`, which means all IPs. If you want to prevent external connections, you can change that behaviour.

For example:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080/tcp ubuntu bash
```

This binds port 8080 of the container to TCP port 80 on 127.0.0.1 (loopback interface) of the host machine.

Comment: Thanks for  response. But I don't want to limit by IP. I just need to block all connections in some time and open it in another time. With your response it closes to outside forever.

Comment: if you share your `iptables-save`, `ip a`, `ip r` and the source ip of the requesting host, we can take a look together